# Turn a GIT repo subfolder into a branch

Tags: git, branch

Is it possible to turn subfolders of a GIT repository into its branches?

Going from one branch with folders

```
-main
  /Folder_A
  /Folder_B
  readme.md
```

To many branches

```
-main
  readme.md
-A
  Content of Folder_A
-B
  Content of Folder_B
```

The reason for this is an import from a TFVC repository to a GIT repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to turn subfolders of a GIT repository into its branches?

Of course, there is a simple command which will do it, it will convert the folder to a branch with all the history

```sh
git subtree split ...
```

[image]

Split the "main" into branches with `git subtree split <path> -b <branch>` and then add you can push the branch to the remote.

```
# split the "main repo"
git subtree split -P path -b <branch1>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Not suitable IMO — `git subtree split` changes the root folder. That is, instead of `/FolderA` the branch will contain the content  of `/FolderA` at the root.

Comment: And once you extract the content you can use it as a branch, the question was to extract subfolders to a branch

Comment: It works great, but if I push everything, the commit history is gone :/ Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Will the branches remain separate from now on? If they will remain separate, fell free to create two new branches from main, say `A` and `B`. Then, in `main`, delete the 2 folders, and in each of the separate branches do the necessary adjustments... say, in `A`

```
git checkout A
git rm readme.md
git rm Folder_B
git commit -m "Removing unnecessary stuff from this project"
```

This should be good enough. This way you get to keep the history of the common development up to this point in all 3 branches. If you don't want that and you would rather have them separate from the  beginning as separate projects, then you should consider using git filter-repo https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: `git mv Folder_A/* .` Gonna remove it? The OP showed the folder is required.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I read it like that would be the new root for those 2 branches. Let me adjust that. Thanks, @phd

Comment: The requirements changed and we ended up using the git subtree split. But your way is great as well